# Analytics Profile Filters - Custom Fields

Tags: google-analytics, filtering, profiles

I'm having problems adding a custom filter to analytics. I am trying to use a custom field to specify the data that I want excluding from the profile.

I have read through endless tutorials and forum posts and cannot get to the bottom of this issue!

I am setting the following (_set CustomVar being called before _trackPageview:

```
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'loggedin', 'true', 1]);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

Setting the profile filter:

Filter Type: Custom filter, Exclude
Filter Field: Custom Field 1
Filter Pattern: loggedin=true (also tried "loggedin", "ture)

The data being displayed in this profile does not exlcude users who do not have this Custom variable in the google analytics code.

Help, Please!

Image:
http://postimg.org/image/xwy3t17d9/

Answer (score 5):

Custom Field 1 is not the same as Custom Var 1. It's not possible to filter by Custom Variables in Google Analytics.

This is possible with Universal Analytics and Custom Dimensions (That replace Custom Vars in this new version of GA). But that will require migrating your web property to Universal Analytics and re-tagging your website.

Comment: note: if trying to filter on a custom dimension you must add the filter at the 'View' level (eg. All Website Data) and not the 'Account' level. you'll only see custom dimensions under the View level